# Cannot add a new method to an Angular TypeScript class (FormGroup)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to add an additional method to Angular's FormGroup class which will set the state of the group + set error state from the server.

I have the following code in a `form-helper.ts` file in my Angular4 app.

```
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export interface FormGroup {
  setValueAndErrors(state: any, memberErrors: any);
}

FormGroup.prototype.setValueAndErrors = (state: any, memberErrors: any) => {
  this.setValue(state);
  // do some stuff with the memberErrors parameter
}
```

But the compiler throws an error on the `FormGroup.prototype.setValueAndErrors` line.

ERROR in C:/dev/AppName/AppName-Client/src/app/shared/utils/form-helper.ts (3,21): Property 'setValueAndErrors' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'.

Comment: Aside from the error you've mentioned, `this` is not going to be what you expect in that arrow function.

Comment: I can cross that bridge when I get to it :) For now I just want to know why this isn't compiling

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following compiles for me:

```
declare module "@angular/forms/src/model" {
  interface FormGroup {
    setValueAndErrors(this: FormGroup, state: any, memberErrors: any): void;
  }
}

FormGroup.prototype.setValueAndErrors = function(this: FormGroup, state: any, memberErrors: any): void {
  this.setValue(state);
}
```

The key seems to be using the module name that refers to the actual module/file that contains the `FormGroup`.

Also, you will need to address your usage of `this`.

Comment: You are like a hero to me :)

Comment: No worries. Answering this has helped me solve a problem that's been bugging me all day.

Comment: Post it as a question + answer on here, to save others the time :)

Comment: you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for the newer version of angular (I am using 13)

```
declare module "@angular/forms" {
  interface FormGroup {
    setValueAndErrors(this: FormGroup, state: any, memberErrors: any): void;
  }
}

FormGroup.prototype.setValueAndErrors = function(this: FormGroup, state: any, memberErrors: any): void {
  this.setValue(state);
}
```