# How To Extend Prototype Of External Library in Angular 2/4?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is a semi-strange problem.

I've got an Angular 4 project with a bunch of external libraries. The one I'm referencing here in particular is the PrimeNG library. More specifically, the Schedule portion which is essentially FullCalendar.

I need to extend this functionality, but I absolutely cannot figure out how to extend the Schedule prototype. If I go into the schedule.js file inside node_modules and edit the file directly, this is easy. I type:

```
Schedule.prototype.refreshEvents = function() { **do things** };
```

But obviously I don't want to have to modify anything in node_modules directly as it will just get replaced next update (and I can't distribute easily to my team).

I've tried declaring it in the component (at various lifecycle hooks), I've tried declaring it in a  in index.html, and more. I'm just not sure what to do here.

Is there any way to extend the functionality of a node_modules plugin like this without directly modifying the file?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try avoiding messing with the distributed js files for PrimeNG by extending from the class they wrote in typescript. Something like `MySchedule extends Schedule`. I haven't actually done that before myself, but I feel like that's a good place to start. I'll link the source code for Schedule from their github here. https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/schedule/schedule.ts

Comment: The biggest problem is that their distributed material is in transpiled JS. Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44927180/6680611