# Augment imported typescript interface

Tags: typescript

I am using a package — [ko-component-router](https://github.com/Profiscience/ko-component-router) — with the following (condensed) type definitions...

*index.d.ts*

```
export { IContext, Context } from './context';
export { Router } from './router';
```

*context.d.ts*

```
export interface IContext {
    $root: IContext;
    $child: IContext;
    $children: IContext[];
    $parent: IContext;
    $parents: IContext[];
    router: Router;
    route: Route;
    params: {
        [k: string]: any;
    };
    path: string;
    pathname: string;
    base: string;
    canonicalPath: string;
}
export declare class Context implements IContext {
  // ...
}
```

*router.d.ts*

```
import { IContext } from './context';
export declare type Middleware = (ctx: IContext, done?: () => any) => {
    beforeRender?: (done?: () => void) => Promise<any> | void;
    afterRender?: (done?: () => void) => Promise<any> | void;
    beforeDispose?: (done?: () => void) => Promise<any> | void;
    afterDispose?: (done?: () => void) => Promise<any> | void;
};
export declare class Router {
    static use(...fns: Middleware[]): void;
}
```

On the consumer side, middleware is registered that can add properties to the context that is passed into the view component, as such...

```
import { Router } from 'ko-component-router'


Router.use((ctx) => ({
    beforeRender() {
        ctx.someProperty = 'foo'
    }
}))
```

As expected, a `Property 'someProperty' does not exist on type 'IContext'` error is thrown by the compiler.

Based on the documentation on [declaration merging](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), I attempted adding the following in order to make the compiler aware of this new property...

```
import { Router } from 'ko-component-router'

declare module 'ko-component-router' {
    interface IContext {
        someProperty: string
    }
}

Router.use((ctx) => ({
    beforeRender() {
        ctx.someProperty = 'foo'
    }
}))
```

But the same error is thrown. I've tried just about everything I can think of, but I'm unable to make the compiler aware of this new property without completely re-implementing the type definitions in my project, which is obviously far from ideal.

Is this possible, and if so, where am I going astray?

Comment: You might need to specify a deeper path in your `declare module` declaration. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44927628/6680611

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in cartant's comment, module augmentation does not work for classes and interfaces that are exported "indirectly" - [this is a known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9127).

It works if you augment the inner module where `IContext` is defined:

```
declare module 'ko-component-router/context' {
    export interface IContext {
        someProperty: string
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, anyone who adds augmentations in this way introduces a dependency on internal structure of your library.

Also, with this augmentation `class Context` does not compile anymore:

> error TS2420: Class 'Context' incorrectly implements interface
>   'IContext'.   Property 'someProperty' is missing in type 'Context'.

So if you add properties to interfaces which are implemented by some classes, these properties must be optional:

```
declare module 'ko-component-router/context' {
    export interface IContext {
        someProperty?: string
    }
}
```

Comment: Was just coming to this conclusion, but this is definitely it. Working around the nasty `declare module 'ko-component-router/dist/context'`by moving any interfaces that are expected to be augmented into the index file itself.

Comment: **Important note**: `declare module thing` is NOT the same as `declare module "thing"`. Had me puzzled for some time. (with the quotes, it tries to resolve the module to existing module matches; without, it assumes you're declaring a whole new module/namespace)