# Extending @types - delete field from interface, add type to field in interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped, typescript-types

I have javascript library with types from npm/@types.

I need to make two fixes to @types which applies only in case of my application, so I can't merge them into DefinitelyTyped repository.

I need to:

1. remove one of fields from interface. Example:

   ```
   // before changes:
   interface A {
           a?:string;
           b?:string;
           c?:string;
   }

   // after changes:
   interface A {
           a?:string;
           c?:string;
   }
   ```
2. add more types to one field in interface. Example:

   ```
   // before changes:
   interface B {
           a?: C;
   }

   // after changes:
   interface B {
           a?: C | D;
   }
   ```

Also I still want to download main @types definitions from external repository.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can be solved using the following method.

```
import { A as AContract, B as BContract, C, D } from './contracts.ts';

// Removes 'b' property from A interface.
interface A extends Omit<AContract, 'b'> { }

interface B extends BContract {
  a?: C | D;
}
```

Comment: TypeScript doc link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys

Answer (score 12):

You cannot override type declarations of existing properties of interfaces in TypeScript but you could do this by extending the type interfaces since you can override property types:

```
interface afterA extends A {
  b?: never;
}

interface afterB extends B {
  a?: C | D;
}
```

Comment: You actually can modify (or augment) type declaration in TypeScript, it's called [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), but how to do that depends on how exactly library types are defined and exported, see [ths question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918373/augment-imported-typescript-interface/46919482) for one example

Comment: @artem thanks! This is really good to know. Unfortunately it doesn't look like declaration merging will work in this case: "Non-function members of the interfaces should be unique. If they are not unique, they must be of the same type."

Comment: Ah yes thanks, I did not even notice that restriction, because I always use it only to add properties.